# by.tagName vs by.css in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

When searching for an element by tag name, we could do:

```
element(by.tagName("my-tag-name"));
```

or, we could also do:

```
element(by.css("my-tag-name"));  // or $("my-tag-name")
```

The latter I've been seeing a lot while reviewing other's merge requests. Probably because `by.css()` is more widely used in general and people often forget that there is a specialized locator.

Is there any functional or performance difference between the two when searching by a tag name?

Comment: Have you tried both ways and seen if there is any performance difference?  That's really the best test.

Comment: Yes, as the names imply, one searches for elements only with that tag name, and the other searches for a full css selector. This is all in the docs too https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css

Comment: @AndyRay okay, I understand what these two methods are for. I am specifically asking about a use case when we are searching for a tag name - and we could do that with both. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the source code of protractor I would say it really depends.  `webdriver.By.css = webdriver.Locator.factory_('css selector');` is the definition for `By.css` which looks like it depends on which webdriver you are using.  So depending on if your webdriver is new enough to incorporate the `querySelectorAll()` method, or has to do more work to figure out what css selector you are using to try to break it down to other selectors, it could very well be that `css()` has to perform more operations than `tagName`, where as tagName always knows what it needs to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Protractor `by.tagName` and `by.css` are inherited from `webdriver.WebDriver`,

Inside webdriver.WebDriver [implement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js#L224), `by.tagName` will be converted to call `by.css` as following:

```
  /**
   * Locates elements with a given tag name.
   *
   * @param {string} name The tag name to search for.
   * @return {!By} The new locator.
   * @deprecated Use {@link By.css() By.css(tagName)} instead.
   */
  static tagName(name) {
    return By.css(name);
  }
```

So `by.tagName(<tag name>)` is equivalent to `by.css(<tag name>)` in Protractor.